# How exacly async.eachLimit() Works? Getting strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm studying the async module documentation and I have the following code:

```
async.eachLimit([9,2,3,4,5,6], 2, function(item, callback){
    if(item == 2 || item == 4){
        callback("Something wrong!");
    }else{
        console.log(item*item);
        callback();
    }
}, 
function(err){
    if( err ){
        console.log('Something wrong!');
    }else{
        console.log('Works!');
    }
});
```

Turns out that when I run this code with limit = 2 the iteration is stopping earlier. If limit = 3 the iteration completes.

What I was expeting is that both completes... Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `async.js` only for asynchronous functions.

Comment: @Bergi do you think the callback knows it's not being called async?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to test this, but I don't think this is done here. Rather, it is *expected* to be called asynchronously, and leading to odd side effects if not.